# Everything is OK. / That's all right

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are these phrases mean the same thing, or does the first one describe all situation in a person's life at this moment but the second one is just a response to something?

Feel free to provide some examples for explanation.

> **Everything is OK.**
>
> **That's all right.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That's all right" would seem to refer to something in the conversation.

> I'm going to be late tonight
>
> That's all right.

"That" refers "being late"

Everything's okay seems to refer to a general state

> How are things?
>
> Everything's okay!

You couldn't swap these over.